# Type II error: statistically nonsignificant but can be actually similar

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation, reporting, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am analysing a rare disease, meaning that a low sample size is inevitable (n = 50 for one group in my case). And I came to a question described as follows.

**Could we somehow differentiate the following two non-significance scenarios in terms of interpretation?**

A - point estimates are quite the same between the groups

B - point estimates are different but CIs overlap, leading to an insignificant p-value

I have scenario A in my data. **Can I somehow say that scenario A provides more evidence to support the non-difference between the groups?** How to say it in statistical language?

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting question (+1) but also seems like a roundabout way of doing [equivalence testing like TOST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test), particularly if you don’t want to declare an effect size of practical equivalence.

Comment: This has been extremely well studied so please read more.  And never compare separate confidence intervals when trying to judge a difference.  Compute the confidence interval for the difference.  And don't assume that point estimates are magical.  They have quite a fuzz around them.